# Getting 401 Unauthorized Even when the user is authenticated (Spring Security)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am working on a simple project with 2 defined roles Admin and User,The admin role has authority to view users by thier usernames but when I login as an admin and i hit the `/admin/users/usernames/{username}`
I get 401 Unauthenticated you can see the request here [postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKjkw.png)

**WHATS THE PROBLEM WITH THE FOLLOWING IMPLEMENTATION?**

**The login Method **

```java
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<User> login(String username, String password) {
        authenticate(username,password);
        User loginUser = findUserByUsername(username);
        UserPrinciple userPrinciple = new UserPrinciple(loginUser);
        HttpHeaders tokenHeader = getJwtToken(userPrinciple);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(loginUser,tokenHeader, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    private void authenticate(String username, String password) {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,password));
    }

    private HttpHeaders getJwtToken(UserPrinciple userPrinciple) {
        String token= jwtTokenProvider.generateJWTToken(userPrinciple);
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add(SecurityConsts.JWT_TOKEN_HEADER,token);
        return httpHeaders;
    }
```

**The User ReST Controlle**

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin/users")
public class UserController {
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return userService.getUsers();
    }

    @GetMapping("/emails/{email}")
    public User findUserByEmail(@PathVariable String email) {
        return userService.findUserByEmail(email);
    }

    @GetMapping("/usernames/{username}")
    public User findUserByUsername(@PathVariable String username) {
        return userService.findUserByUsername(username);
    }

    @JsonView(BodyView.BasicUser.class)
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public User addUser(@RequestBody User user) throws UsernameExistsException {
        return userService.addUser(user);
    }
    @JsonView(BodyView.BasicUser.class)
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<User> login(@RequestBody User user) {
        return userService.login(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
    }
}
```

**POM.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>FM6-App</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>FM6-App</name>
    <description>FM6-App</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**The Web Security Configurer Adapter**
The public URLS:

```java
public static final String[] PUBLIC_URLS ={"/users/admin/login/**","/admin/users/register/**","/demandes/**","/criteres/**"};
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true,
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private JWTAuthorizationFilter jwtAuthorizationFilter;
    @Autowired
    private JWTAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private JWTAccessDenielHandler jwtAccessDenielHandler;
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/users/login/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(SecurityConsts.PUBLIC_URLS).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/utilisateur/**").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_USER")

//                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(jwtAccessDenielHandler)
                .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthorizationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean(name = "authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public  AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception{
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
```

**JWT Authorization Filter**

```java
@Component
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JWTTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase(SecurityConsts.OPTION_HTTP_METHOD)){
            response.setStatus(SecurityConsts.OK.value());
        }else if(request.getRequestURI().equals("/users/login")){
            filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
        }
        else {
            String autorizationHeader =  request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
            if(autorizationHeader == null || !autorizationHeader.startsWith(SecurityConsts.TOKEN_PREFIX)){
                filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
                return;
            }
            String token = autorizationHeader.substring(SecurityConsts.TOKEN_PREFIX.length());
            String username = jwtTokenProvider.getSubject(token);
            if(jwtTokenProvider.isTokenValid(username,token) && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){

                List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthorities(token);
                Authentication authentication = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(username,authorities,request);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }else {
                SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            }

        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
    }
}
```

**The Cross-Origin Configuration class**

```java
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH")
                        .allowedHeaders("*")
                        .allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: and when you enable spring security debug logs they show you what reason? also, spring security has a full JWT implementation, so please consult the spring security documentation on how to actually implement the handling of JWTs as there is already a built in JWT filter and much more. I dont really see the point of using a security framework if you do not intend to use it at all with all the custom self written code. Custom security is in general bad practice.

Comment: add this logging.level.root=DEBUG to your config and run the code again  ... this will let us know what's not configured properly and then I can help.

Comment: @Padikodwo the log is so huge i noticed a an eception keeps repeating

Comment: javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication
 at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1083) ~[na:na]
 at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:637) ~[na:na]
 at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you debug the application? The error you mentioned  in the comments `javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication` is IDE-related, there is stackoverflow post about it, so this is not the issue.

Try to debug code and check:

1. If you, actually, get to `JWTAuthorizationFilter`
2. If your user is identified as admin user here: `List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthorities(token);`
3. Check if you pass a correct and the newest token to Postman in `Authorization` header; check url (in the screenshot you have provided url is incorrect, it is `useErnames`)
4. What is the value of `SecurityConsts.TOKEN_PREFIX`? It should include space, i.e. 'Bearer '

**UPDATE**
Based on the comment below regarding my 2nd question (although I meant to check the values during runtime in debug mode, but anyway..)

```
String[] ADMIN_AUTHORITIES = {"ADMIN_ROLE"};
```

In the security config you are looking for `hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")`, but assigned your admin with `"ADMIN_ROLE"`. Wording is different: ROLE_ADMIN vs ADMIN_ROLE.
When you update one of them, be aware that Spring adds word "ROLE" to the authority name by itself in some cases. So try with and without this prefix.

Comment: SecurityConsts.TOKEN_PREFIX is indeed 'Brearer '
For the Authorities 
```java 
public static final String[] USER_AUTHORITIES = {"USER_ROLE"};
    public static final String[] ADMIN_AUTHORITIES = {"ADMIN_ROLE"};
```

Comment: @ElwafiElmehdi, I gave updated the answer. Just wanted to mention that initially I asked about runtime `authorities` values which are retrieved from token. You can see them when you are in debug mode. But I assume that you assign these `authorities` when you create your admin user. So this answer can also be used.

Comment: Thank you so mush, i was really idiotic to not see that mistake.

Comment: Thank you Kamenska I was writing down from an old project i developped and because my intership organism had a difrant role architecture i mad the mastike in those authorities