# Problem with Authentication (SPRING SECURITY)

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, jwt

I have a problem, I'm using spring security to create endpoint login. After login success the response with token will be created. But when I using postman to send request(I'm using correct method, the header contain Bearer token, token still alive I also can decode token) but I always be 401 error
here is my config

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .cors()
                .and().csrf().disable() 
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/register/", "/api/test/all", "/api/test/login")
                .permitAll() 
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/users/")
                .hasAnyAuthority("CUSTOMER", "ADMIN", "EXPERT") 
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/test/customer")
                .hasRole("ROLE_CUSTOMER")
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/test/customer")
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin() 
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/api/test/customer")
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthenticationEntryPoint() {
                    @Override
                    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
                        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authException.getMessage());
                    }
                })
                .and()
                .build();
    }
//and the endpoint I want to access after login success(the full is /api/test/customer)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('CUSTOMER')")
    @GetMapping("/customer")
    public String home() {
        return "Home after login for customer";
    }
```

I want to fix that as soon as possible
[I'm using postman to send request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvxZe.png)

Comment: show screen shots of how exactly you send the request

Comment: I add the screenshot above

Answer (score 0):

There might be issue with the role naming.

1. Which role does your user have? "CUSTOMER" or "ROLE_CUSTOMER"? It should be "ROLE_CUSTOMER" in the database.
2. Note that you double check user's role and use different wording with and without "ROLE_" prefix

- in the security config:

  `.requestMatchers("/api/test/customer").hasRole("ROLE_CUSTOMER")`
- in the method annotation

  `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('CUSTOMER')")`

Spring after version 4, I guess, adds "ROLE_" frefix on its own, so you can check `hasRole("CUSTOMER")`, but the role in the database should be with prefix, i.e. "ROLE_CUSTOMER". Some spring versions don't add prefix, so you have to check `hasRole("ROLE_CUSTOMER")`.

Please, check this answer here as well, it might help
[StackOverflow: getting-401-unauthorized-even-when-the-user-is-authenticated-spring-security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71810226/getting-401-unauthorized-even-when-the-user-is-authenticated-spring-security/71819541#71819541)

Comment: I try 2 way store in database is ROLE_CUSTOMER and CUSTOMER, both way not working at all

Comment: But have you tried to use ROLE_CUSTOMER in the DB and update your code, in _both_ places to hasRole('CUSTOMER') ? Also you can debug it and see what is happening in your JWTAuthorizationFilter ot any other place you use to read token?

Comment: actually, it work in 2 way. I fix it already, I miss validate token, so token always be 401

Answer (score 0):

I miss validate token, so the token send to the server always be 401

Comment: If the problem with your question was incorrect code elsewhere, you should close the question yourself as not meaningful since it cannot help anyone else.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35044109)

Comment: @siggemannen really? [answer] doesn't say that.